Can SentinelOne act in a different way on a Windows 10 than on Windows 11?
Is it possible that the same SentinelOne (S1 - an antivirus software) policy, when applied to Win 10 and 11, can act differently? Can this depend on the system version or even on the particular hardware?
The same domain user:

logs on an old PC with Windows 10 Pro and on a new Dell Latitude 5540 with Windows 11 Enterprise,
invokes sfc /scannow in the cmd console run as administrator.
On Win 10, the command is run, S1 doesn't report any problem.
On Win 11, the console disappears, the command is blocked, msiexec is quarantined and the laptop is disconnected from the network.

Is this possible?
Long story and the context follows:
I am a user of a company-owned PC connected to a company network. I have administrative rights on this PC, applied by policies set per domain user groups level.
Some time ago, our company changed the AV software to S1. Although S1 is sometimes heavy on CPU/memory, the change seemed more or less transparent. I can see the logs of S1 (as displayed by its monitor program) and they are clear. And this is on an old PC with Windows 10 Pro.
Recently, I got a new Dell Latitude 5540 with Windows 11 Enterprise, intended to replace my PC.
I logged on with the same domain user and waited for the system to apply all company policies, install updates, etc. Standard procedure.
Then I installed the latest OpenVPN software. It's optional in our company.
S1 blocked the installation, several errors were displayed, virtual tap cards were not installed...
So I uninstalled it, seeing several errors again.
Then I started the cmd in admin mode and invoked sfc /scannow. Maybe an overkill, but I use sfc from time to time, especially when something goes wrong... just a habit.
The cmd console disappeared and S1 showed some new warning. I am not sure now, but I think that some file was quarantined at this step, probably msiexec.exe.
And the laptop was disconnected from the Internet.
I was quite puzzled with this behaviour beacuse I have never experienced this before.
I thought that resetting the network might help, so I tried ipconfig /renew, netsh winsock reset, etc. All without success, every time S1 killed the console and showed a new error.
During these tries, S1 put some files to quarantine, I don't remember all of them and am not sure which files were quarantined after an execution of which particular command, but I remember for sure that one of the quarantined files was msiexec.exe.
OK, last resort... let's reset the computer! :-)
After the reset, the system didn't start and automatic system restore failed.
So the system was bricked and I asked the company helpdesk to reinstall it.
Later on, I contacted helpdesk to do something with this strange behavior of S1. A network admin tuned some policies and now S1 does not disconnect the Internet any more, but it still reports some cmd commands as suspicious, sometimes it even reports that it has quarantined something... although... strange... the quarantine is empty.
After that, with the help of this helpdesk admin (approving the "risks" reported by S1), I checked this list of commands to be found suspicious by the S1:

fsutil dirty set C:
chkdsk /F C:
sfc /scannow
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
ipconfig /flushdns
gpupdate /force

I believe the list is not complete, but you may get an idea... these are normal commands to maintain a computer, nothing really sophisticated or strange.
I suspect that trying to install the OpenVPN would not succeed, too, but I am not eager to try again.
The most strange thing comes now:
The helpdesk admin that was helping me, told me that he supports thousands of workstations, many similar to mine, and encountered this problem for the first time. He tried running sfc /scannow on his Windows 11 (Enterprise, the same as mine) machine and encountered no problems. He claims he has the same S1 policies as me.
Neither he nor I have an idea what may cause the strange behaviour of S1 on my laptop.
The laptop seems to work OK, otherwise. Chkdsk, sfc and dism don't report any errors. But S1 still finds these commands suspicious.
Any idea, any comment is appreciated.

I figured out what causes SentinelOne to treat shell commands as threats.
This is WindHawk software used to Tweak the Windows UI. Although S1 allows for installation of WindHawk and doesn't report it as a threat, when WH is installed, certain shell commands are treated by S1 as suspicious.
WH is an excellent software, but it causes problems with S1.
